# How to make a USB storage device undetectable in u-boot?

Tags: linux, usb, embedded, usb-drive, u-boot

I need to do a test in an embedded system where I plug in the USB storage device and do "usb start" but the USB storage device is not detected.
I have a working pendrive. How to make it undetectable in u-boot?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all partitions from the USB device using the fdisk command. Ideally without any partitions, u-boot will not detect if there is no filesystem/partitions. I do not know of any way for the USB device not being detected at all. If this is for a test case, the above method should work fine.